# Does Python's garbage collector harm my application?

Tags: python, multithreading, reference, garbage-collection

Is it bad in Python, when I don't hold a reference of a Thread I created with: `threading.Thread(target=worker_method)`? Is it possible that the garbage collecor does anything to it, which affects the stability of my application?

Comment: In this case GC should not harm it. It's rather your design/code.

Comment: Do you ever start your thread?

Comment: The thread would keep running, but you would no longer have any handle to it in order to say...stop it?

Comment: My understanding is that the thread dies when the worker function has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread will keep running regardless, but the downside is that you don't have a handle to the thread any more in order to communicate with it.

A simple test shows that even when the thread object goes out of scope, its still running:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def t_func():
    print "Sleeping"
    sleep(5)
    print "Done Sleeping"

def test():
    t = Thread(target=t_func)
    t.start()

>>> test()
Sleeping
Done Sleeping
```

Even if you were to delete the `t` thread object right after starting it, it will keep running. But you really should be keeping track of thread that you start, to make sure they finish or to monitor if they are alive. And also, to shut them down cleanly if need be.

Comment: Not having a reference is not always a downside.  If it's a pool thread, some other thread class that is to run for the lifetime of the app and communicates via queue or a thread that just operates completely independently from the rest of the app, why keep a reference?

Comment: @MartinJames: Yea you are right, on a more advanced application of threading, you would have those situations where something else is managing them or providing a communication path. I was fixated more on the simple application I think.